Automatically supress all TS errors by adding ts-expect-error comment (codemod)
I want to enable strict mode in tsconfig, but I also do not want to fix 100 errors at once.
I'd like some codemod that could just add
// @ts-expect-error this one appeared after introducing strict mode, please fix it

to all the places where TS reports the new errors.
This way I can start using strict mode for the new code and gradually update the codebase when I work with the older code. Instead of fixing hundreds errors at once.
Does anybody know about codemod for that?
